# Initializing pointers, difference between c and c++ compilers (gcc-4.3.4)

Tags: c++, c, pointers, gcc

my effort to understand pointers better, I wrote this code:

`int *a = 17;`

`printf("%d", a+3);`

It compiled fine under c using gcc-4.3.4: http://ideone.com/abotd

And yet it failed to compile with c++: http://ideone.com/IdGHy

I would like to know why.

Also, the output, as you can see from the first link is 29. I pseudo-understand what's happening: sizeof(int) is 4, and when I wrote a+3 instead of adding 3 to 17, 3*4 is being added.

Still, I would appreciate if someone can explain it more eloquently.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For C++ version try this:

```
int *a = (int *)17;
printf("%d", a + 3);
```

And yes your explanation is correct...

This is called pointer arithmetic and works the way you said. Note however that the code you are using here where you assign a constant value to a pointer to an `int` is rarely done in real life. The pointer value usually comes from some kind of memory allocation functions e.g `malloc` in C or `new` in C++ (although `new` isn't a function).

Comment: This is close to the answer I seek.
What I'm not sure I understand is how can it be treated both as a pointer for pointer arithmetic and as an int for deriving the '17' value.

Comment: This is one of the features of the C/C++ languages. Yes, 17 is an `int` literal but in C, the compiler automatically casts it to an `int *` while in C++, you have to manually cast it. I hope this is what you were asking.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly: **Step 1** - The compiler sees `a` that is `int *` and understand that it should dereference it by itself (in c++ I have to do it myself) - so this is how I get the '17' part.
**Step 2** - The compiler then sees that it should add 3 to `a` but since `a` is of type `int *` it knows that it should increment by 3*4 (because sizeof(int) = 4). The end result is 17 + 12 = 29.
Is this correct?

Comment: I think you don't really understand the meaning of "dereference"...dereference means when you get the value stored at a location pointed to by a pointer e.g. `int b = *a` assuming that `a` was of type `int *`, then `*a` is what we call dereference-ing. So I think your understanding is correct except for the part where you call "casting`, dereferencing. So Step 1 is: The compiler sees `a` that is `int *` and understand that it should cast it by itself (in c++ I have to do it myself) - so this is how I get the '17' part.

Comment: "dereference-ing" meaning taking a pointer and looking at the actual value that it points to, right?
And `a` is a pointer to an int, right?
And we got the value that it points to which is `17`, right?
Then why do you say that it is casting and not dereferencing?
Also, when you say that the compiler casted `a` of type `int *` by itself, what did it cast it to?

Comment: 17 is just a location in the memory. When you say `int *a = 17`, it means you just want to have a pointer which you call `a` to an `int` which is in location '17' in the memory. You don't know what is in that location. Could be nothing at call...could be something being used by the OS (very likely). But in actuality, 17 is an `int` literal so C++ complains that you are trying to convert an `int` to an `int *` but C is fine with it because it know that you are trying to point to the location 17 in memory. Get it?

Comment: YES! ^_^ Thanks for patience.

Comment: @mtahmed "_in C, the compiler automatically casts it to an int *_" completely wrong! Please, don't try to teach C as you don't know this language.

Comment: @curiousguy I would have appreciated you comment more if you had told me how I am wrong and what it actually is...knowledge is not going to come to me from the sky...I would appreciate if you would correct me...thanks.

Comment: @mtahmed In C and in C++, a pointer cannot be implicitly converted to an integer type, and vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

It's not correct C++ code.

```
int * a = 17;
```

This is invalid. You can't implicitly convert an `int` to a pointer. You *could* cast it, but I wouldn't do it if I were you.

Comment: To cast it: `int *a = (int*)17`. Just don't try to modify `a` or your application will crash.

Answer (score 2):

You want something like:

```
int foo = 17;
int* a = &foo;
printf("%d\n", (*a) + 3);
```

The code you posted attempts to set the pointer to an address at `17`, which is probably not a valid address, and even if it were you'd need to cast from the `int` to a pointer (`int* a = (int*)17;`).   You then add to that address, and output the address that's three `int` sizes above it.  I really don't think that's what you want.